# RichFaces.ajax() ignores options.clientParameters

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm globally setting clientParameters like this (globally for testing purposes, I will narrow it down to the specific use case once it works):

```
var originalRichFacesAjax = RichFaces.ajax;
RichFaces.ajax = function(source, event, options) {
    options.clientParameters = options.clientParameters || {};
    options.clientParameters.render = "@all";
    options.clientParameters.execute = "@all";
    originalRichFacesAjax.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

yet in the response I'm only getting a tiny partialupdate.

Why doesn't JSF/RichFaces rerender the entire page?

Comment: Are you using Groovy or something? The syntax looks different.

Comment: Maybe post an example Facelet's page. Does the update work as expected if you set the client-side properties on the Facelets page instead of the backing-bean? (I assume that's possible.)

Comment: No, this is standard JavaScript (RichFaces.ajax() is the RichFaces clientside method for AJAX requests) I don't use my own Facelets for that, the RichFaces.ajax() stuff is handled by RichFaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RichFaces do not check the client parameters for render/execute, instead they check for `org.richfaces.ajax.component` and get the values from the component.

You can remove the parameter after it's been added, or you can use `jsf.ajax.request()` instead.

Comment: Which `options.clientParameters` are used by RichFaces, and why not `render` and `execute`?  You mean I could remove the `options['org.richfaces.ajax.component']` property? But it seems like it is being added inside of `RichFaces.ajax()` so I don't have access to it without forking the lib, no?

Comment: `RichFaces.ajax()` is a wrapper around `jsf.ajax.request()` (which is itself being overwritten for queuing purposes), you can catch it there. If a request originates from a RichFaces component the `render/execute` values are taken from the component, if not it's handled the standard way.